# How to use MDX Filter function to exclude specific members by Name

Tags: filter, mdx

I need an MDX query to show several sets of data with a filter to exclude certain ID numbers.
For example,  this query will INCLUDE only one ID number

```
SELECT [Measures].[Gross Amt] ON COLUMNS,
FILTER( 
   [Policy].[Policy Name].[Policy Name]
*  [Policy].[Policy ID].[Policy ID],
[Policy].[Policy ID].Name = "622743"
)
ON ROWS
FROM EXPOSURE
```

What I want to do is EXLUDE a group of ID's like this

```
SELECT [Measures].[Gross GAAP Par OS Amt] ON COLUMNS,
FILTER( 
   [Policy].[Policy Name].[Policy Name]
*  [Policy].[Policy ID].[Policy ID],
[Policy].[Policy ID].Name 
    ****NOT IN [PolicyB].[Policy ID].AllMembers****
)
ON ROWS
FROM EXPOSURE
```

What is the correct syntax to exlude the members of PolicyB ?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you do not need to [Filter](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Filter.php)() anything.

The first use case could be rewritten like:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Gross Amt] ON COLUMNS, 
  { [Policy].[Policy Name].[Policy Name] } * { [Policy].[Policy ID].[622743] } ON ROWS 
FROM EXPOSURE
```

For the set of ID to exclude, you could use the - operator:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Gross Amt] ON COLUMNS, 
  { [Policy].[Policy Name].[Policy Name] } * ( [Policy].[Policy ID].members - { [Policy].[Policy ID].[622743], ... } ) ON ROWS 
FROM EXPOSURE
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: (upped) might be worth adding the `EXCEPT` version of second script: I think it is more explicit and easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

MarcP has given you the answer but another interesting possibility is a `sub-select`. This will roll up your Policy ID into the All member of that hierarchy.

Here is an example against the AdvWks cube:

```
SELECT 
  [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year] ON 0
 ,
  {[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS} * {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 1
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    [Customer].[Customer].&[20075] ON 0
  FROM [Adventure works]
);
```

Therefore applied to your scenario:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Gross Amt] ON COLUMNS
 ,
  {[Policy].[Policy Name].[Policy Name]} * {[Policy].[Policy ID].MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    [Policy].[Policy ID].[622743] ON 0
  FROM EXPOSURE
);
```

Then to exclude in a slightly more obvious way than using the `-` operator I'd suggest using `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Gross Amt] ON COLUMNS
 ,
  {[Policy].[Policy Name].[Policy Name]} * {[Policy].[Policy ID].MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    Except
    (
      [Policy].[Policy ID].MEMBERS
     ,[Policy].[Policy ID].[622743]
    ) ON 0
  FROM EXPOSURE
);
```

The following (I think) is exactly the same as Marc's second script just syntactically different:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Gross Amt] ON COLUMNS
 ,
    {[Policy].[Policy Name].[Policy Name]}
  * 
    Except
    (
      [Policy].[Policy ID].MEMBERS
     ,{[Policy].[Policy ID].[622743]}
    ) ON ROWS
FROM EXPOSURE;
```

A further thought is that you can also add a member to the hierarchy that represent all exluding your set like this:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Policy].[Policy ID].[All excl 622743] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      Except
      (
        [Policy].[Policy ID].MEMBERS
       ,{[Policy].[Policy ID].[622743]}
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Gross Amt] ON COLUMNS
 ,
    {[Policy].[Policy Name].[Policy Name]}
  * 
    [Policy].[Policy ID].[All excl 622743] ON ROWS
FROM EXPOSURE;
```

Comment: Thanks Guys for your responses,  this is very helpful.  What I want to do however, is not exclude one specific ID that I already know, but a set of ID's that are in a different dimention [PolicyB].  PolicyB has [Policy ID] and [Policy Date] members.  So what I am trying to do is select Policy ID's from Policy execpt for whatever ID's are in PolicyB for a seleted date.

Comment: @BillyWinter your question only uses one dimension ... `[Policy].`. If this is wrong then change the question.

Comment: The key part of the question shows the [PolicyB] dimention: [Policy].[Policy ID].Name 
    ****NOT IN [PolicyB].[Policy ID].AllMembers****